# BODMAS or PEMDAS with single number within bracket e.g. : 72÷3(4)+7 operation should be divide first or treat bracket?

Tags: arithmetic

I was going though basic school equation and answers by community members were different. They were divided in 2 sections, like given below.

Question:   $ 72÷3(4)+7$

```
Option 1: Divide by 3 then x 4
Option 2: Divide by 12
```

I was wondering even if there is single number within brackets, it should be treated first i.e. $72 ÷ 12 + 7$; but many said it is wrong as parentheses or brackets defines the operation precedence of variables only within the bracket. Once the equation within the bracket is solved to single digit then it should be treated as multiplication sign.

i.e $72 ÷ 3 \cdot 4 + 7$;

Different calculators do show different results for the same, see attached images.

1. showing divide by 3 first then multiply by 4, thus giving answer as 103.
   [image]
2. Showing divide by $12$ by treating $3(4)$ before division, thus giving answer $13$.
   [image]

I know that while these calculators are based on their embedded chips, but which is correct way?

Comment: Pemdas also includes the convention that multiplication/division and addition/subtraction are performed starting from the left, so we divide by $3$, and then multiply by $4$.

Comment: See, the third secret solution is to not use the symbol ÷ to avoid any ambiguity, and only think of division as multiplication by a fraction (outside of arithmetics) :)

Comment: The correct answer is to slap whoever wrote such a terribly formatted expression.

Comment: Maybe write $72\div 3(4)+7=72\div 3\cdot 4+7=\frac{72}3\cdot 4+7$ since $a(b)=a\cdot b$. Even [*Wolfram Alpha recommends*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNYY2.jpg) your question.

Comment: Chat GPT also suggests that 72÷3(4)+7; equals to 13.

Comment: The chat thing is a very smart text completion thing, it knows absolutely no math. Using it as a reference will only lead to pain.